# How do I read a single text file and have the values placed into a cookie cutter sentence format?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Here's the content of the text file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

I want it to read and print out like this
The number ____ was at 00:00.
The number ____ was at 01:00.
and so on...

Here is what I have so far. I have found a lot about reading a .txt file but not much with how to take the info and format it in such a way.
One part of the code is for solving another objective which is to find the avg, min,, and max value. I just need help with the printing out the list format.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberThingy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create new Scanner object to read from the keyboard
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Ask human for file name
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your data file with it's extension i.e Whatever.txt: ");
    String fileName = in.next();

    // Access the file provided
    Scanner fileToRead = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    double Sum = 0;
    int NumberOfEntries = -1;
    double HighestValue = 0, LowestValue = 0;
    boolean StillRecording = true;
    double CurrentValue;
    while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
        if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble())
        {
            NumberOfEntries++;
            CurrentValue = fileToRead.nextDouble();

            if (StillRecording) 
            {
                HighestValue = CurrentValue;
                LowestValue = CurrentValue;
                StillRecording = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                HighestValue = Math.max(HighestValue,CurrentValue);
                LowestValue = Math.min(LowestValue, CurrentValue);
            }

            Sum += CurrentValue;
        } 
        else 
        {
            fileToRead.next();
        }   
    }
   System.out.println("Here are your resutlts:");
   System.out.println("Minimum Temp = " + LowestValue);
   System.out.println("Maximum Temp = " + HighestValue);   
   System.out.println("Average Temp: " + Sum/NumberOfEntries);   
   System.out.println("There are " + NumberOfEntries + " temp recordings.");
   System.out.println("It dipped down to 32 F " + FreezeCounter + " times.");
}
}
```

Thank you for your time and patience! I'm a student and love this community's enthusiasm.

Comment: Your example is a bit hard to understand, what does the `01:00` mean? Is it a time on a clock? Is it a position? Could you explain this a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do have a lot of good things in place already, but as you are new to these concepts I'd recommend breaking this program into small working examples--little "aha" success moments.

For example, with the Scanner class, hard-code in the file location and simply get it to print the values from the file.

```
Scanner fileToRead = new Scanner(new File("c:\\hard-coded-file.txt"));

while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
    if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println(fileToRead.nextDouble());
    } 
    else 
    {
        fileToRead.next();
    }   
}
```

Once you can do that, then add in your analysis logic. As of right now, it appears that your highest and lowest values will likely turn out to be the same value.

Lastly, consider reviewing the class and variable naming conventions for Java (you should do this for every language you work in) as, for example, standard variable names are written in camelCasing rather than PascalCasing as you have done.

EDIT/UPDATE

In regards to the cookie cutter format, I think you are on the correct track. To achieve what you are wanting, you will likely have to add a println statement within the while loop and print as you go, or you could experiment with something like a list of strings

```
LinkedList<String> outputStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
```

and adding the strings

```
outputStrings.add("The number ___ was at 00:00"));
```

to that list. You could then loop through the list at the end to print it all at once. Note that you may consider looking into String.format() to get leading zeroes on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about printf? Here is a cheatsheet I used when I was learning java.

https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

```
System.out.printf("Today's special is %s!", "tacos");
```

Basically the method will replace whatever `%s %f` you have in the first string with the variables listed after the first string. It prints "Today's special is tacos!" You have to match the types right: `%s` is for string, `%f` for floating points.

Its all in the link.

Comment: Thank you! What is the Ex. for?

Comment: I get this output :/ with this line: System.out.printf("The temp was % at 00:00 \n", CurrentValue);           
The temp was  0x1.18p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.0p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.fp4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.cp4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.9p4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.6p4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.7p4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.9p4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.ap4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.ep4t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.0p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.3p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.48p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.58p5t 00:00 
The temp was  0x1.68p5t 00:00

Comment: Sorry ex was for example. ill take it out. I think you want to use %d since you are reading integer numbers. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right direction, RedRunner!